# find_by_name Ancestry Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, menu, rubygems, tree

I have been working on implementing the Ancestry gem in my rails app, I have almost got it working the way I want it to.

I am having problems with the following line of code from the [Ancestry README docs](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry).

```
TreeNode.find_by_name('Crunchy').subtree.arrange
```

The code that I am using in my app is as follows:

```
Message.find_by_name('FedEx').@messages.arrange
```

With this, I am getting an error message:

```
syntax error, unexpected tIVAR
...find_by_name('FedEx').@messages.arrange );@output_buffer.saf...
...
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, or explain to me what `TreeNode` and `subtree` should be replaced with?

Comment: As the error says, that's a syntax error.You can't accessor object properties like that (i.e. using instance variables). Why are you using `@messages.arrange` rather than `subtree.arrange` as the docs say?

Comment: @Alex When I use `.subtree.arrange` I get an `undefined method 'subtree' error` so I assumed this was incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive what you want is: `Message.find_by_name('FedEx').subtree.arrange`.
`Message` class should implement ancestry via `has_ancestry` according to the README.

Comment: By '`Message` class should implement ancestry via `has_ancestry`' I assume you mean step 3, bullet point 2 on the README: 'Add to app/models/[model].rb: has_ancestry'? If so, I have done this. When I use `Message.find_by_name('FedEx').subtree.arrange` I get an `undefined method` 'subtree' error

Comment: Can you paste the whole message "undefined method 'subtree' for X"? Is it by any chance "undefined method 'subtree' for nil:Nil class" ?

Comment: Yes that's right `undefined method 'subtree' for nil:Nil class`

Comment: Well, then, regarding ancestry, everything is in order. The problem here is that `Message.find_by_name('FedEx')` cannot find the given record, it probably does not exist, so instead of returning a Message instance (that responds to #subtree) it returns a nil object (that does not respond to #subtree). Create the message with the `FedEx` name first.